# How to run cython command line options

Tags: windows, command-line, cython

I have recently started using cython and now want to use the -a tag as shown http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types to see how my code is doing.  However to use this I need to access the cython command line program.  My question is how to do this.  I am running windows and tried adding C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\Cython to my path environmental variable and the typing cython on command line, but this didn't work.  Thank you for your time

Comment: Define "didn't work". Did you get an error message?

Comment: I added the Cython directory to path, and did the following on command line:C:\Documents and Settings\student>cython; in response I got:
'cython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts and executables are stored in the Scripts/ directory in the python install directory. In my case, I installed python3 in C:\Python31, so I added C:\Python31\Scripts to my path. This allows me to use cython on the command line.

Note that I have to type "cython.py" and not "cython" on the command line, since the Scripts/ directory contains a "cython.py" file, and not a "cython" file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the -a (annotation) HTML file, you do NOT necessarily need to use the command line. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075375/1272672