# Cython -a flag (to generate yellow-shaded HTML) without command line

Tags: cython

When you run from the command line

```
$ cython -a mycode.pyx
```

you get a really nice HTML "annotation" file with yellow shading to indicate slow python operations vs fast C operations. You also get this same HTML file as a link every time you compile Cython code in Sage. My questions are: (1) Can I get this HTML file if I'm compiling using distutils? (2) Can I get this HTML file if I'm compiling using pyximport? Thanks!!

Comment: You can always call the `cython` command using `subprocess`. Otherwise, read the Cython source code; it's not tremendously hard to follow.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks to larsmans's comment and the [Cython email list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/cython-users/LZcC92mGx94/discussion), I now have many satisfying options to generate the "annotate" HTML file without leaving IPython:

(1) Use subprocess...

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["cython","-a","myfilename.pyx"])
```

(2) Turn on the global annotate flag in Cython myself, before compiling:

```
import Cython.Compiler.Options
Cython.Compiler.Options.annotate = True
```

(3) Pass `annotate=True` into `cythonize()` [when using the [`distutils` compilation method](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-distutils)].

It seems that pyximport does not have its own direct option for turning on annotation.

Comment: As one might guess, it's `cython3` for Python 3.

Comment: `annotate` is not to be found in http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives and adding it as `#cython: annotate=True` does not generate the file, so I just used your option 3 (successfully).

Comment: @handle - Option (2) has always been undocumented. Did you actually try it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I tried the "magic" compiler directive assuming this way might work also. I did not try setting an attribute as in (2). (3) works.

Comment: All the three options can work if it doesn't work, please delete `.c`, `.so` and `.o` files and rerun `python setup.py build_ext --inplace ` to compile it. Your answer is really helpful.