# Faster bit-level data packing

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, cairo

An 256*64 pixel OLED display connected to Raspberry Pi (Zero W) has 4 bit greyscale pixel data packed into a byte (i.e. two pixels per byte), so 8192 bytes in total. E.g. the bytes

```
0a 0b 0c 0d (only lower nibble has data)
```

become

```
ab cd
```

Converting these [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) either obtained [from a Pillow (PIL) Image](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes) or a [cairo ImageSurface](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/surfaces.html#class-imagesurface-surface) takes up to 0.9 s when *naively* iterating the pixel data, depending on color depth.

Combining every two bytes from a Pillow "L" (monochrome 8 bit) Image:

```
imd = im.tobytes()
nibbles = [int(p / 16) for p in imd]
packed = []
msn = None
for n in nibbles:
    nib = n & 0x0F
    if msn is not None:
        b = msn << 4 | nib
        packed.append(b)
        msn = None
    else:
        msn = nib
```

This (omitting *state* and saving float/integer conversion) brings it down to about half (0.2 s):

```
packed = []
for b in range(0, 256*64, 2):
    packed.append( (imd[b]//16)<<4 | (imd[b+1]//16) )
```

Basically the first applied to an RGB24 (32 bit!) cairo ImageSurface, though with crude greyscale conversion:

```
mv = surface.get_data()
w = surface.get_width()
h = surface.get_height()
f = surface.get_format()
s = surface.get_stride()
print(len(mv), w, h, f, s)

# convert xRGB
o = []
msn = None
for p in range(0, len(mv), 4):
    nib = int( (mv[p+1] + mv[p+2] + mv[p+3]) / 3 / 16) & 0x0F
    if msn is not None:
        b = msn << 4 | nib
        o.append(b)
        msn = None
    else:
        msn = nib
```

takes about twice as long (0.9 s vs 0.4 s).

The `struct` module does not support nibbles (half-bytes).

`bitstring` does allow packing nibbles:

```
>>> a = bitstring.BitStream()
>>> a.insert('0xf')
>>> a.insert('0x1')
>>> a
BitStream('0xf1')
>>> a.insert(5)
>>> a
BitStream('0b1111000100000')
>>> a.insert('0x2')
>>> a
BitStream('0b11110001000000010')
>>>
```

But there does not seem to be a method to unpack this into a list of integers quickly -- this takes 30 seconds!:

```
a = bitstring.BitStream()
for p in imd:
    a.append( bitstring.Bits(uint=p//16, length=4) )

packed=[]
a.pos=0
for p in range(256*64//2):
    packed.append( a.read(8).uint )
```

Does Python 3 have the means to do this efficiently or do I need an alternative?
External packer wrapped with ctypes? The same, but simpler, with Cython <s>(I have not yet looked into these)</s>? Looks very good, see my answer.

Comment: Did you try numpy using vector operations (for example, use reshape to combine `x>>4` and `x&0xF` using some concat and reshape, where `x` is your data vector)?

Comment: Not yet, since I don't know much about NumPy. I think I'll try Cython first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down to 130 ms from 200 ms by [just wrapping the loop in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function)

```
def packer0(imd):
    """same loop in a def"""
    packed = []
    for b in range(0, 256*64, 2):
        packed.append( (imd[b]//16)<<4 | (imd[b+1]//16) )
    return packed
```

Down to 35 ms by *[Cythonizing](https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-distutils)* the same code

```
def packer1(imd):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop"""
    packed = []
    for b in range(0, 256*64, 2):
        packed.append( (imd[b]//16)<<4 | (imd[b+1]//16) )
    return packed
```

Down to 16 ms with type

```
def packer2(imd):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed"""
    packed = []
    cdef unsigned int b
    for b in range(0, 256*64, 2):
        packed.append( (imd[b]//16)<<4 | (imd[b+1]//16) )
    return packed
```

Not much of a difference with a "simplified" loop

```
def packer3(imd):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed"""
    packed = []
    cdef unsigned int i
    for i in range(256*64/2):
        packed.append( (imd[i*2]//16)<<4 | (imd[i*2+1]//16) )
    return packed
```

Maybe a tiny bit faster even (15 ms)

```
def packer4(it):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed"""
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    return [ (it[i*2]//16)<<4 | it[i*2+1]//16 for i in range(n) ]
```

Here's with [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

```
>>> timeit.timeit('packer4(data)', setup='from pack import packer4; data = [0]*256*64', number=100)
1.31725951000044
>>> exit()
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -m timeit -s 'from pack import packer4; data = [0]*256*64' 'packer4(data)'
100 loops, best of 3: 9.04 msec per loop
```

This already meets my requirements, but I guess there may be further optimization possible with the input/output iterables (-> unsigned int array?) or accessing the input data with a wider data type (Raspbian is 32 bit, [BCM2835](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/processors.html#bcm2835) is ARM1176JZF-S single-core).

Or with parallelism on the [GPU](https://github.com/Idein/py-videocore) or the multi-core Raspberry Pis.

---

A crude comparison with the same loop in C ([ideone](https://ideone.com/cpoo3z)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define SIZE (256*64)
int main(void) {
  uint8_t in[SIZE] = {0};
  uint8_t out[SIZE/2] = {0};
  uint8_t t;
  for(t=0; t<100; t++){
    uint16_t i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE/2; i++){
        out[i] = (in[i*2]/16)<<4 | in[i*2+1]/16;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It's apparently 100 times faster:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ gcc p.c
pi@raspberry:~ $ time ./a.out

real    0m0.085s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.010s
```

---

Eliminating the the shifts/division may be another slight optimization (I have not checked the resulting C, nor the binary):

```
def packs(bytes it):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed"""
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    return [ ( (it[i<<1]&0xF0) | (it[(i<<1)+1]>>4) ) for i in range(n) ]
```

results in

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'from pack import pack; data = bytes([0]*256*64)' 'pack(data)'
100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 msec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s 'from pack import packs; data = bytes([0]*256*64)' 'packs(data)'
100 loops, best of 3: 12 msec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s 'from pack import packs; data = bytes([0]*256*64)' 'packs(data)'
100 loops, best of 3: 11 msec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s 'from pack import pack; data = bytes([0]*256*64)' 'pack(data)'
100 loops, best of 3: 13.9 msec per loop
```

Comment: Slight error: the actual data is a bytes object, which makes things slightly slower, even if bytes is specified as parameter type. To get the Cython HTML report, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058933/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377115/typing-python-sequence-to-cython-array-and-back for further optimization.

Comment: Down to 150 us (1000x faster) using a memory view on an array (`bytearray` works similarly, `bytes` does not yet: a bug in cython requires a mutable sequence), optimizing the loop calculations and creating and returning another `array`.