# Cython: How to declare numpy.argwhere()

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I tried to Cythonize part of my code as following to hopefully gain some speed:

```
# cython: boundscheck=False
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import time

cpdef object my_function(np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] array_a,
                     np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] array_b,
                     int n_rows,
                     int n_columns):
    cdef double minimum_of_neighbours, difference, change
    cdef int i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim =1] locations
    locations = np.argwhere(array_a > 0)

    for i in locations:
        minimum_of_neighbours = min(array_a[i - n_columns], array_a[i+1], array_a[i + n_columns], array_a[i-1])
        if array_a[i] - minimum_of_neighbours < 0:
            difference = minimum_of_neighbours - array_a[i]
            change = min(difference, array_a[i] / 5.)
            array_a[i] += change
            array_b[i] -= change * 5.
        print time.time()

return array_a, array_b
```

I can compile it without an error but when I use the function I got this error:

```
from cythonized_code import my_function
import numpy as np

array_a = np.random.uniform(low=-100, high=100, size = 100).astype(np.double)
array_b = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=20, size = 100).astype(np.double)

a, b = my_function(array_a,array_b,5,20)

# which gives me this error:    
# locations = np.argwhere(array_a > 0)
# ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Do I need to declare `locations` type here? The reason I wanted to declare it is that it has yellow colour in the annotated HTML file generated by compiling the code.

Comment: `where` is a tuple of indices, one array per dimension.  `argwhere` is `np.transpose(where...)`.  So it is an array, 2d, with columns match dimensions. Number of rows is unknown.

Comment: It is declared right above, but with a wrong `ndim`.

Comment: Changed to `cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim =2] locations`  and now I got this error:  `locations = np.argwhere(array_a > 0)
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int_t' but got 'long long'`

Comment: It seems that I should use `np.int64_t` in `cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim =2] locations`

Comment: Usually, one would look up the properties of the numpy-array
 `locations.ndim` and `locations.dtype` and then deduce the type for `locations`. And not just decide which type `locations` should be...

Comment: You have answered the question in your comments. I will accept it if you provide it as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea not to use the python-functionality `locations[i]`, because it is too expensive: Python would create a full-fledged Python-integer* from the lowly c-integer (which is what is stored in the `locations`-numpy array), register it in the garbage collector, then cast it back to `int`, destroy the Python-object - quite an overhead.

To get a direct access to the lowly c-integers one needs to bind `locations` to a type. The normal course of action would be too look up, which properties `locations` has:

```
>>> locations.ndim
2
>>> locations.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

which translates to `cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim =2] locations`.

However, this will (probably, can not check it right now) not be enough to get rid of Python-overhead because of a Cython-quirk:

```
for i in locations:
    ...
```

will not be interpreted as a raw-array access but will invoke the Python-machinery. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48103343/5769463).

So you will have to change it to:

```
for index in range(len(locations)):
      i=locations[index][0]
```

then Cython "understands", that you want the access to the raw c-int64 array.

---

- Actually, it is not completely true: In this case first an `nd.array` is created (e.g. `locations[0]` or `locations[1]`) and then `__Pyx_PyInt_As_int` (which is more or less an alias for `[PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow][2]`) is called, which creates a `PyLongObject`, from which C-`int` value is obtained before the temporary `PyLongObject` and `nd.array` are destructed.

Here we get lucky, because length-1 numpy-arrays can be converted to Python scalars. The code would not work if the second dimension of `locations` would be `>1`.

Comment: This is very interesting. When I tried `with no gil` before the for loop in my little experiment, I was receiving this error `Iterating over Python object not allowed without gil`. At that time I tried looping using range and indexes to see if it allows using without gil but never thought it might increase the speed!